# Laravel - Jetstream - Routing authentication api/web

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

What I got:

- created a new jetstream project (inertia) and `Features::api()` enabled in `jetstream.php` config,
- `web.php`:

  ```
  Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/testweb', function () {
      return "test web called";
  })->name('testweb');
  ```
- `api.php`:

  ```
  Route::get('/testapi', function(){
      return 'api called';
  })->middleware('auth:sanctum');
  ```
- also I created a test API token

now when I call **`/testweb`** in the browser and I am **logged in** I get **"test web called"**

when I am **logged out** and call it I get **redirected to login view**

---

when I make the **API request WITH the token**

I get the expected result **"api called"**
BUT
when I **don't add a token** to the request
I don't get a `401` or so but I get a **`200` with an "empty" view** (with livewire i see it is the loginview, so i think with inertia it is the loginview too)

---

what is the cause of that? do I have to handle it myself? if yes, where and how?

---

additional note:
I made the API request with POSTMAN, does it differ if I do not set the header as `Accept: application/json`?

Comment: You've not added middleware inside your api.php file for the routes that's why you're getting an empty view.

Comment: @HassaanAli maybe i do not understand it, but i thought I did with ```Route::get('/testapi', function(){
        return 'api called';
    })->middleware('auth:sanctum');```

Comment: The thing with Laravel convention is we need to define the web routes and API routes differently and if we need to add a middleware in Api route as well in order to redirect user to a 401 error page.

Comment: the thing is i do not want to be redirected when calling an API, when the header "Accept: application/json" is missing, I get redirected when not authenticated, if the header is present, I get the "wanted" error response when not authenticated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the request is made with that head included

`Accept: application/json`

then the **Authenticate Middleware** will know what to do and decide

if it will redirect it or

just send back a 401 response.